# SDK integration in android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I have added Facebook `SDK` and Google-play-services_lib as library in my project . I have deleted `android-support-v4.jar` from my project Lib folder. Now I am facing with following problem

```
[2014-09-26 15:47:47 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple DEX files define Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
[2014-09-26 15:47:47 - Mmatching] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
```

Comment: Just uncheck your `Android Dependencies` checkbox from `Java Build Path -> Order and Export`.

Comment: @Thanks PG_Android. My problem solved.

Comment: if this helpful u can accept as a answer.

Answer (score 2):

This means that you have multiple files defined for your project settings.

For that,

Go to the,

`Project Properties -> Java build path -> Libraries -> Remove Android dependencies`

**To be more specific** -

Just removing the `facebook-android-sdk.jar` file from libs worked for me as well as it refers to the facebook related jar which I had in multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this error by following these steps:

1. Right click on the project and open the properties.
2. Go to 'Java Build Path..'
3. Go to Order & Export tab. Unmark 'Android Private Libraries' & Click 'OK'.

and clean your project. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Just Uncheck your `Android Dependencies` checkbox from `Java Build Path -> Order and Export`.